# JPanel how to drag and move free area?

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, awt

Consider the following JPanels. `MyMainPanel` is considered a “free space” or canvas to put objects onto, and `SomeCustomObject` is an item that is placed onto that canvas. So you can think of `MyMainPanel` the parent panel, which includes other panels (which are objects a user can interact with).

```
class MyMainPanel : JPanel() {
    init {
        preferredSize = Dimension(1000, 1000);
        this.background = Color.white

        val handler = MyMouseAdapter()
        addMouseMotionListener(handler)
        addMouseListener(handler)
        add(SomeCustomObject())
    }
}

class SomeCustomObject : JPanel() {
    init {
        background = Color.GRAY
        preferredSize = Dimension(200, 50);
    }
}
```

Also consider the `MyMouseAdapter` below, which is supposed to provide functionality to drag and move the free space:

```
class MyMouseAdapter : MouseAdapter() {
    var me: MouseEvent? = null

    override fun mousePressed(e: MouseEvent) {
        me = e
    }

    override fun mouseDragged(e: MouseEvent) {
        val component = e.component
        // what to do here to help with the dragging of the free space?
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to find a way such that when the mouse clicks and drags on the `MyMainPanel` it will move the objects in that panel also, creating the illusion of a free space where a user can drag in the free space to move the canvas around.

Is this even a good way to implement something like this?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`JDektopPane` / `JInternalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) combination? The API provides the ability to drag the internal frames around, out of the box.

Comment: Thank you, did not know about this. Will check it out.